# loop function in matlab to repeat a function

Tags: matlab, numeric

I'm a biology student trying to use matlab, my mathematical and informatic knowledge is thereby limited. However I've tried to write some code to obtain the following:

I have a function y=f(t) that describes the growth of every individual. y=f(t) has 8 variables that are constant but are different for each individual. The velocity curve is obtained by differentiating the y=f(t) function. a picture of both the growth and velocity curve can be seen below. The red curve is the growth curve and the blue curve the velocity curve.

the function is described by y(t)= m1*(1-1/(1+(m2*(m0+m8))^m5+(m3*(m0+m8))^m6+(m4*(m0+m8))^m7)). 
t is here the independent variable. m1 to m8 are variables that are constant for each individual but differ between individuals.

What I would like to obtain is

- the inflection points (both t and f(t) values) of the growth function
- the asymptotic value of the growth function
- the corresponding maximum height of the differentiated function
- the minimum height of the differentiated function before the maximum height is

  % set variabelen
  syms t;
  m1=xlsread('jongens0','A1:A10');
  m2=xlsread('jongens0','B1:B10');
  m3=xlsread('jongens0','C1:C10');
  m4=xlsread('jongens0','D1:D10');
  m5=xlsread('jongens0','E1:E10');
  m6=xlsread('jongens0','F1:F10');
  m7=xlsread('jongens0','G1:G10');
  m8=xlsread('jongens0','H1:H10');

  % set loop
  for i=1:10

  % define function and differentiated function
  y(i)=m1(i).*(1-1./(1+(m2(i).*(t+m8(i))).^m5(i)+(m3(i).*(t+m8(i))).^m6(i)+(m4(i).*(t+m8(i))).^m7(i)));
  dy(i)=diff(y(i))./dt;

  % information extraction
  a=max(dy(i));
  b=fminsearch(dy(i),x0,[0,a]);
  c=max(y(i));
  d=limit(y(i),inf);
  e=inflect_pt((y(i)));

  A = [a b c d e]

  % write information to excel
  xlswrite('output0',A)

Comment: This is pretty basic MATLAB. Did you read any tutorials or try [searching for an answer on the web](http://goo.gl/aDZz4) first?

Comment: I did and I had a feeling it's a very basic question but I kept making the same mistakes so I hoped to find some answers here.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html), it should get you more familiar with MATLAB loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using incorrect MATLAB syntax.

```
for(i=0,t++,i<50)
```

is closer to C++ syntax than MATLAB. (Although not correct C++ syntax, as pointed out by @John)

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with this code:

```
fori=1:50,;
i;
end;
```

but it's not correct. The `,` after `1:50` is not supposed to be there. You do not want `;` in the end of the `for i=1:50` line, nor after `end`. (`;` is used to suppress output, and these lines does not produce any)

It's hard to tell exactly what you want to achieve, but I think something like this is close:

```
y = zeros(size(t,1),50);

for i = 1:50
  y(i,:) = m1(i).(1-1./(1+(m2(i).(t+m8(i))).^m5(i) ...
      +(m3(i).(t+m8(i))).^m6(i)+(m4(i).(t+m8(i))).^m7(i)));
end
```